# Force current location identifier (blue dot) to snap to the nearest path

Tags: ios, gps, mkmapview, mapkit

I am new to Stackoverflow, so I apologize if my research wasn't good enough, but I couldn't find an answer to my question.

I am building a trail based application (iOS for now). I will be surveying the undefined area with GPS Surveying equipment and plan to export it as a KML or GPX file. With that being said, I will want a user to be able to use my app to track their location and navigate the trails I provide.

I am concerned that their current location (blue dot or arrow) will not always appear to be on the trails as a GPS signal is not always correct. I would like their location to always be displayed on the trail if within X amount of distance (for example, if they are 10 feet away or more they probably not trying to follow my defined trails). Essentially I want the blue dot to snap to the nearest position on the path I defined.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can move the map-provided blue dot. If you ask to display it, it uses the current location as determined by the location manager.

However, you could write an app that monitored the user's current location, and when it received location updates, moved around a custom annotation on the map that looked like the blue dot, and snapped it to the closest trail as you described.

I would suggest deferring this until you get some experience working with the map kit and the location manager. There are lots of other things to worry about first.

Comment: thanks for the reply! I am not set on using the "blue dot" as the current location indicator, so I do like your suggestion. Essentially, I want an experience like Google Maps or Apple Maps or Map Quest (etc.) where you see your location mapped on/against the road (or trail in my case) and it never happens to fall off. If you watch a navigation app while someone is driving it is just one smooth progression for the most part. Does that clarify more of what I am looking for? I would like to make a mini Google Maps for the trails I define (no directions, just free view).

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to move the official blue dot. You probably can't do it and even if you could you shouldn't because it is widely accepted to mean your current location, not "the closest part of the trail to your current location". If your data is detailed enough you could find the nearest point, check if the point before or after that is closer to the current location and then draw a marker somewhere between the two. But really, if someone is within 10 feet of the trail they'd have to be quite zoomed in to notice that the blue dot isn't exactly on the line, so like Duncan, I recommend not trying this unless you're 100% sure it'll sell more apps.

Comment: I agree with you. I do not want to try and move the "blue dot" even if it is possible. I am just trying to figure out a way a user can us my maps of the trails I define to navigate the different paths while having a user experience like Google Maps. My vision is an angled view (birds eye/3D view) so the user can navigate appropriately.